# Increment labels

Tags: python, powershell

I need to create 300k unique labels that would comply to this regex ^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}$

So, starting with AAAA0000, ending to ZZZZ9999.
Could someone help me developing some code to achieve this (either powershell or python) ?

Tx a lot for your help !

Comment: Q1) When you say unique does that mean you need it randomized and still remain unique when the code is queried or simply an incremental AAAA0000->AAAA0001 etc.? Do you need to keep track of the last used string if the program stops?

Comment: May be you can create python code using looping to compose quadword of A-Z and 0-9 to meet your regex expression.

Comment: There are >4.5 billion such labels (requires roughly ~40GB of disk space to store ascii-encoded with a single-char separator) - are you really sure you _need_ to create all of them? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen : You're right, I don't need all of them :) I need approx 300k entries

Comment: 300K labels from AAAA0000 onwards, or 300K random unique labels from the sequence? Please don't make us guess what you're asking about

Comment: unique is mandatory (either random or not). I have edited my question to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the python `itertools` module:

```py
from itertools import product
import string

for letters in product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=4):
    for numbers in product(range(0,10), repeat=4):
        print(''.join(letters) + ''.join([str(i) for i in numbers]))
```

Output:

```
AAAA0000
AAAA0001
AAAA0002
AAAA0003
AAAA0004
AAAA0005
AAAA0006
AAAA0007
AAAA0008
AAAA0009
AAAA0010
AAAA0011
AAAA0012
...
```

If you don't need all of them but only one after another, you can implement a generator like this:

```py
from itertools import product
import string


def label_generator():
    
    for letters in product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=4):
        for numbers in product(range(0,10), repeat=4):
            yield (''.join(letters) + ''.join([str(i) for i in numbers]))
            

for x in label_generator():
    print(x)
```

If you only want a limited number of labels, you can try to add a parameter to the generator:

```py
from itertools import product
import string


def label_generator(num_max = 300000):
    
    num = 0
    for letters in product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=4):
        for numbers in product(range(0,10), repeat=4):
            if num < num_max:
                yield (''.join(letters) + ''.join([str(i) for i in numbers]))
                num += 1
            else:
                raise StopIteration


for x in label_generator(20):
    print(x)
```

Comment: That's great. I will test it and let you know. Tx !

Comment: @zecam You are welcome. You have given some more details in your question, I think I have adopted the answer accordingly.

Comment: I asked for a Ford, you gave me a Rolls ! I have no enough words to thank you again :)